# How can I get the facebook customer chat svg?

Tags: css, svg

I want to have the facebook customer chat svg icon from this site: https://craftedmiracle.com/. How can I get it? Thanks

I want the icon that have round white background EXACTLY on the above web. Fb also provides messenger icon but it does not look like the version on the web

I inspect the web but don't know how to extract the svg tag to .svg file

Comment: See my edited answer. I have edited just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit this link:

https://icons8.com/icons/set/facebook-messenger

This has facebook icons that you want in many forms. Click on **Download** > Select **SVG** tab > Select the Size of icon that you wish to download > Finally **Download**.

**EDIT:**

Or I have created an SVG for you:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 172 172" style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><path d="M86,172c-47.49649,0 -86,-38.50351 -86,-86v0c0,-47.49649 38.50351,-86 86,-86v0c47.49649,0 86,38.50351 86,86v0c0,47.49649 -38.50351,86 -86,86z" fill="#3498db"></path><g><path d="M86,28.66667c-30.1,0 -54.46667,23.22 -54.46667,51.6c0,14.90667 6.59333,28.09333 17.2,37.55333v25.51333l22.36,-13.47333c4.58667,1.14667 9.74667,2.00667 14.90667,2.00667c30.1,0 54.46667,-23.22 54.46667,-51.6c0,-28.38 -24.36667,-51.6 -54.46667,-51.6z" fill="#ffffff"></path><path d="M51.6,97.46667l28.66667,-31.53333l14.33333,14.33333l25.8,-14.33333l-28.66667,31.53333l-14.33333,-14.33333z" fill="#3498db"></path></g><path d="" fill="none"></path></g></svg>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's nice. I can inspect the web and get the svg but fail to display it as an svg file. Could you see what's wrong? Your version works

https://pastebin.com/VjxWxSGv

Comment: Why are you inspecting the element if I have provided the entire svg element?

Comment: Your version looks different than what I need (color, etc) but it works great

Comment: It has the xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg" element. Please check it.

Comment: @coinhndp, you can check this codepen: https://codepen.io/rohan-rao-the-bashful/pen/ZEbyKzp  You don't have to inspect the element to get the SVG, just copy the svg tag and everything inside it in your application.

Comment: @coinhndp, if it is working please accept this answer so that others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

https://iconmonstr.com/facebook-messenger/

https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-messenger

Also - if you're using Font Awesome, they have an icon for it as well.

You can also download it and serve it locally, depending on your needs.

Comment: Yes but I want the icon that have round white background like on the web. Fb also provides messenger icon but it does not look like the version on the web

Comment: You can specify the fill/color of svg icons. There are many places to get it. You style it with css.